# При деплое Django-приложения на heroku появляется ошибка TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, heroku

возникла такая ошибка при развертывании Django-приложения на Heroku.

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/blog/includes/pagination.html  (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/includes/pagination.html  (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/includes/pagination.html  (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/blog/templates/blog/includes/pagination.html  (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/users/templates/blog/includes/pagination.html  (Source does not exist)
```

Хотя при разработке на локальном сервере, шаблон всегда отображался. Несколько раз проверил, и кажется, что никаких ошибок с написанием быть не может.

Вот часть моего файла setting.py, отвечающая за шаблоны:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

В других вопросах видел совет, добавить папку вручную в 'DIRS', но это бессмысленно, потому что в тексте ошибки видно, что шаблон ищется в правильной папке.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь или указание направления, где искать.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какой именно шаблон не загружается и где он находится.

Comment: Собственно шаблон называется pagination.html, находится в blog/templates/blog/includes/, я включаю его в другие шаблоны через тег include